Crear base de datos y tablas SQLite desde Net MAUI
Buenas noches estimados colaboradores, ahora vengo a pedir ayuda sobre Net MAUI.
bueno he creado un proyecto para practicar sobre las migraciones, ya saben crear la base de datos, las tablas (en este caso una tabla), he hecho todo en en base a la documentación y algunos videos y con ayuda de Git Hub. luego de haber creado la clase, en DBContext la clase para la conexiox. y tambien he agregado el codigo en em MauiProgram.cs; pero cuando intento ejecutar las migraciones para crear la base de datos con la tabla. me sale un mensaje done, osea hecho, pero no se crea la carpeta de migraciones. y no puedo ver donde se crea la base de datos y la tabla.
estas son las clases que he creado
    public class Categoria
{
    [Key]
    public int IdCategoria { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}

El DBContext
public class InventarioDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }

    public InventarioDbContext()
    {
            
    }
    public InventarioDbContext(DbContextOptions<InventarioDbContext> options) : base(options) 
    {
            Database.Migrate();
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string conexionDb = $"Filename={ConexionDb.DevolverRuta("venta.db")}";
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(conexionDb);
        //optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();

        Console.WriteLine($"Usando la base de datos en: {conexionDb}");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Categoria>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(c => c.IdCategoria);
            entity.Property(c => c.IdCategoria).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        });

    }
}

La clase conexion
    public class ConexionDb
{
    public static string DevolverRuta(string nombreBaseDatos)
    {
        string rutaBaseDatos = string.Empty;

        if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
        {
            rutaBaseDatos = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            rutaBaseDatos = Path.Combine(rutaBaseDatos, nombreBaseDatos);

        }
        else if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
        {
            rutaBaseDatos = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            rutaBaseDatos = Path.Combine(rutaBaseDatos, "..", "Library", nombreBaseDatos);
        }
        else if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.WinUI) // Agregado para Windows
        {
            rutaBaseDatos = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            rutaBaseDatos = Path.Combine(rutaBaseDatos, nombreBaseDatos);
        }

        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Ruta de Base de Datos", rutaBaseDatos, "OK");
        });

        return rutaBaseDatos;

    }
}

en la clase MauiProgram
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif
            // Configuración del DbContext usando la ruta proporcionada por ConexionDb
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<InventarioDbContext>(options =>
            {
                string dbPath = ConexionDb.DevolverRuta("venta.db"); // Llama al método en la clase ConexionDb para obtener la ruta
                options.UseSqlite($"Filename={dbPath}");
            });

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }

Estas serían las clases involucradas en lo que es la parte de las migraciones.
por ejemplo este es uno de los mensajes que me muestra y en este momento debería crearse la carpeta de migraciones.
PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Startup project 'MauiPruebaMigracion' targets platform 'Android'. The Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools don't support this platform. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-pmc-tfms for more information.
El otro comando
PM> dotnet ef database update
No project was found. Change the current working directory or use the --project option.
Cuando ejecuto un DIR, se me muestra estos directorios:
PM> dotnet ef database update
Build started...
Build succeeded.
dotnet : The specified deps.json
[C:\Users\rober\source\repos\MauiPruebaMigracion\MauiPruebaMigracion\bin\Debug\net8.0-android\MauiPruebaMigracion.deps.json] does not exist
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1

dotnet ef database update

  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The specified d... does not exist:String) [], RemoteException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError




Cuando intento hacerlo nuevamente, me muestra este mensaje.
PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Startup project 'MauiPruebaMigracion' targets platform 'Android'. The Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools don't support this platform. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-pmc-tfms for more information.
No sé si esta parte es correcta, pero el proyecto lo tengo en esta dirección de Git Hub
https://github.com/Roberto010877/MauiPruebaMigracion.git
Muchas gracias por ayudarme y orientarme en el proceso.
Buenas noches

Creo haber leído alguna vez que no era posible, así como lo estás haciendo. Tienes que crear un 2do proyecto (uno de biblioteca) ahí colocas lo correspondiente a la base de datos y luego en tu proyecto MAUI referencias a esa biblioteca. Me parece que el problema se debe a como MAUI maneja el target (plataforma destino) de la compilación, ya que para ese tipo de proyecto tiene muchas, en cambio para un proyecto de biblioteca tiene una sola

Buenas noches, ahora entiendo creo que también ví algo así pero no se mencionaba que se debía hacer así. Mañana mismo buscaré información gracias
